# javascript:void(0) in href and onClick not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The following code is part of a larger function that determines whether something is online or not and returns the code to the page and displays a 'remote support' button. This works fine in all browsers including IE 7,8. This does not work in IE 9. The button in its entirety should be able to clicked but on IE 9 only the top portion of a 110px button is clickable, basically around 2px.

Is there a way to get this to work in IE9 or no?

```
if(strpos($response, "TRUE") > -1){
    echo "<a
href='javascript:void(0)'
onClick=\"window.open('".$instantChat."','_blank','toolbar=no, status=no, menubar=no,
titlebar=no, location=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no, height=570, width=400'); return false;\" 
    class='instantChat'
>Remote Support</a>" ;
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

**Edit 1**:

I wanted to clean the code up a bit and I tried using the `button` element instead of an anchor but it screws up inside Chrome and doesn't work.

May I also add that this button is rotated 270 degrees and the text is sideways. This is intended.

Here's the new piece of code that simplifies the above but does not fix the problem.

```
if(strpos($response, "TRUE") > -1){
    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='openChat();' class='instantChat'>Remote Support</a>" ;
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a CSS issue not a Javascript issue based on the fact that it works but only if you click on very top two pixels.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly I definitely did have some trouble with CSS because I was using CSS3 and some of the elements weren't supported by IE so I had to use ms-filter etc. Not sure why that would have an effect on IE9 only.

Comment: because IE 7 and 8 barely has any CSS3 support

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick='openChat();' class='instantChat'>Remote Support</a>
```

every browser handles things differently. The best way to do it is taking the onclick out totally and define a jquery handler for it. Something like

```
$('.instantChat').click(function(){
    // open chat code here
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you don't want a link, you want a button. So why not use the button element? Then you don't need to worry about the javascript:void bit.

I'd also ditch the onclick attribute entirely. I suspect the capitalisation of it is where things are going wrong for you and you could probably fix it.

You'd be better off adding a data-action='openChat' attribute. Then adding a handler elsewhere that handles element clicks and :
1. Checks if the element clicked was a button.
2. Checks if it has a data-action attribute
3. If it has a data-action checks if it is openChat.
4. If it is openChat it opens a window.

Standard separating model from view stuff.

Comment: I wanna do this in one line as the coding is already difficult as it is and IE9 is making things a pain. I don't understand why it works in every single browser but it does not work in IE9.